# Implicit declaration of function 'funcName' ; Previous implicit declaration of 'funcName' was here?

Tags: iphone, c

I get 2 warnings:

- Implicit declaration of function 'funcName'
- Previous implicit declaration of 'funcName' was here

Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just what the warning says.  An "implicit" declaration of a function is usually one that isn't defined yet.  Could you also include the line of code that is giving you that warning?

My first thought is that you are not `#import` ing some code you need so the compiler knows where to find that function.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've mostly had that problem with macros - was that your case?